# Annotation configuration for kafka High level consumer

Tags: spring-integration

I wonder if there's a way to configure the kafka-integration Inbound Channel Adapter as explained in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka using Java annotations instead of xml. I don't quite get the clue on it. I was able to configure the Message Driven Channel Adapter but now I need one that doesn't re-reads consumed messages in case of re-starting the server

Answer (score 0):

See the [main Spring Integration Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations) for configuring with annotations; also see the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl).

We are adding more and more java configuration examples; see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/ip.html#ip-annotation) for example.

The kafka high-level message source would be configured as an `@InboundChannelAdapter` `@Bean`.